# is there an option to call a method with argument and get a default value in the method?

Tags: python-2.7, default-value

I have the next code:

```
def foo(i_String, i_TimeOut=10s):
    """ do some stuff"""

if __name__ == __main__:
    userInput = raw_input("Run with default time? Yes / No ?")
    time = none if userInput=="Yes" else 5s 
    foo("abc", time)
```

is there a way to call the foo method with a time parameter, but get the default value of i_Timeout (10s) with the same signature from the calling method and not the parameter that was passed?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `inspect` module:

```
import inspect
def get_default_args(func):
    args, varargs, keywords, defaults = inspect.getargspec(func)
    return dict(zip(args[-len(defaults):], defaults))
```

As such:

```
def foo(i_String, i_TimeOut=10):
    print i_TimeOut

if __name__ == "__main__":
    userInput = raw_input("Run with default time? Yes / No ?")
    time = get_default_args(foo).values()[0] if userInput=="Yes" else 5 
    foo("abc", time)
```

---

```
>>> if __name__ == "__main__":
...     userInput = raw_input("Run with default time? Yes / No ?")
...     time = get_default_args(foo).values()[0] if userInput=="Yes" else 5 
...     foo("abc", time)
... 
Run with default time? Yes / No ?Yes
10
>>> if __name__ == "__main__":
...     userInput = raw_input("Run with default time? Yes / No ?")
...     time = get_default_args(foo).values()[0] if userInput=="Yes" else 5
...     foo("abc", time)
... 
Run with default time? Yes / No ?No
5
>>>
```